# Authorize.net Get Transaction ID from Server Integration Method

Tags: php, authorize.net

I want to integrate my application with Authorize and I need to get the transaction ID to save this information in database. The question is, can I do this with SIM? I know you can set a URL to get back to you homepage, but is it possible to send the transaction ID back to homepage?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

**[Relay Response](https://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/The-Authorize-Net-Developer-Blog/Relay-Response-Basics-and-Troubleshooting/ba-p/9536)**

> Relay Response is a feature available to merchants using Server Integration Method (SIM) or Simple Checkout. It instructs the payment gateway to return transaction results to the merchant using an HTML form POST to a specified URL on the merchant's Web server. A script or program at the URL can be used to create a custom receipt page using the transaction information. The custom receipt page is then relayed back to the customer's browser. Relay Response does not redirect the end user back to the merchant’s server, but relays the page content to the end user instead of displaying the Authorize.Net default receipt page.

**[Silent Post](http://www.johnconde.net/blog/all-about-authorize-nets-silent-post/)**

> This feature allows you to specify a URL, or Web address, to which the payment gateway should copy the transaction response that is sent to the configured Relay Response URL. If you are not using Relay Response, the feature allows you to specify an additional URL to which transaction responses can be posted.

If you're looking for sample PHP code I wrote an article that includes that [here](http://www.johnconde.net/blog/handling-authorize-net-silent-post-with-php/).

My recommendation is to use Relay Response as it gives you an opportunity to customize the receipt page your user's see. (Although you can use both as they do not conflict with each other).

(*I am the author of both Silent Post articles*)